# Use column names for `x` error in linear regression model in R, How to solve this

Tags: r

Error: Please use column names for `x`
This is my code,

```
 model = train(Name = colSums(data[, c(2:780)])
```

> Error in train.default(Name = colSums(data[, c(2:780)])) :
> argument "x" is missing, with no default

```
model = train(Name,data=data, method="lm", trControl=mycontrol)
```

> Error: Please use column names for `x`

I'd like to do K-fold Cross validation LINEAR regression model using the caret package.

I get the error Error: Please use column names for x.

Is there any other way for Calculating R-squared, RMSE value for linear regression using R

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `train()` function properly. You can see from [its documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/caret/man/train.html) that the first argument to the train() function should be a dataframe, a formula, or a recipe.

I recommend that before you go on, you work through [the chapter in the official package book](https://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html) to understand its modelling syntax. Otherwise, even if you resolve this little issue, you will run into many more.

Even better, I suggest that you dump the `caret` package and that you spend your time learning **[`tidymodels`](https://www.tidymodels.org/)** instead, the new framework created by the creator of the caret package. `caret` is now archaic; `tidymodels` encapsulates current best practices for modelling in R. You should probably begin by working through the articles in [their getting started guide](https://www.tidymodels.org/start/).